# Rendering data from a dictionary inside json after saving data into JSONField in Django

Tags: json, django, dictionary

I am working on a django project whereby I am using JSONField to save data into the database of the model. Everything works fine but I am having issues when trying to render the data into the html template. The data saved into the database is as shown below.

```
{'degree': ['BSc','MSc'],
     'designition': [
         'content writer',
         'data scientist',
         'systems administrator',
     ],
     'email': 'maunarokguy@gmail.com',
     'name': 'Brian Njoroge',
     'phone': '+918511593595',
     'skills': [
         'Python',
         ' C++',
         'Power BI',
         'Tensorflow',
         'Keras',
         'Pytorch',
         'Scikit-Learn',
         'Pandas',
         'NLTK',
         'OpenCv',
         'Numpy',
         'Matplotlib',
         'Seaborn',
         'Django',
         'Linux',
         'Docker'],
     'total_exp': 3,
     'university': ['gujarat university', 'wuhan university', 'egerton university']}
```

I am looking for a way to render them such that in the html, I will have something that displays the dictionary data inside skills and university as a list.
Here is the template for loop

```
{% for skill in user.profile.json_data %}
  {{skill}}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is the models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_images')
    bio = models.TextField()
    resume        = models.FileField('Upload Resumes', upload_to='resumes/', null=True, blank=True,default='resume.docx')
    json_data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is the views

```
@login_required
def myprofile(request, user_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    context = {'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: have you tried to `import json` and `transform the json in to dict` ? you can do it in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a JSONField in the models
`skills = models.JSONField('Skills', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)` and then in your template

```
{% for skill in user.profile.skills %}
 {{skill}}
{% endfor %}
```